# When adding content to json file php error occurs

Tags: php

I'm learning php and started following a youtube video for a project.

When i accept contents from my `json` file and code it to add new contents to it, an error occurs.

**Error-**

> Warning: Undefined variable $json_encode in /Users/montekkundan/Downloads/coding/php/newtodo.php on line 16

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Value of type null is not callable in /Users/montekkundan/Downloads/coding/php/newtodo.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Users/montekkundan/Downloads/coding/php/newtodo.php on line 16

**php code-**

```
<?php
// echo "<pre>";
// var_dump($_POST);
// echo "</pre>";

$todoname = $_POST['todoname'] ?? "";
$todoname = trim($todoname);

if($todoname) {
  $json = file_get_contents('todo.json');
  $jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
  $jsonArray[$todoname] = ['completed' => false];
  // echo "<pre>";
  // var_dump($jsonArray);
  // echo "</pre>";
 file_put_contents('todo.json', $json_encode($jsonArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)) ;
}
?>
```

Comment: $json_encode is a function, not a variable, just remove `$`, so it should be `json_encode($jsonArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change
`file_put_contents('todo.json', $json_encode($jsonArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));`
to `file_put_contents('todo.json', json_encode($jsonArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));`
that's because you are trying to call json_encode variable, json_encode is not a variable.